# Invalid character, Font that I can use to convert text

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have some code that I have written for adobe pro.  When I copy paste it into the script location I get invalid character.  The problem is that the quotation marks are not standard.  Thus the error code.  However, I have over 1400 quotation marks.  Does anyone know the font I can download to quickly change all of my quotes to the correct version.  I have tried various monospace fonts and they have not worked.  Here is a sample of what I am working with.

```
 var a=["60x13.5", "60.5x13.5", "63x14", "63.5x14", "65.5x14.5", "66x14.5","68.5x15", "69x15", "71x15.5", "71.5x15.5", "72x15.5", "74x16", "74.5x16", "77x16.5", "77.5x16.5", "79.5x17"];

 var b=[“61x14”, “61.5x14”, “62x14”, “62.5x14”, “63.5x14.5”, “64x14.5”, “64.5x14.5”, “65x14.5”, “66x15”, “66.5x15”, “67x15”, “67.5x15”, “68x15”, “69x15.5”, “69.5x15.5”, “70x15.5”, “70.5x15.5”, “71.5x16”, “72x16”, “72.5x16”, “73x16”, “73.5x16”, “74.5x16.5”, “75x16.5”, “75.5x16.5”, “76x16.5”, “76.5x16.5”, “77x17”, “77.5x17”, “78x17”, “78.5x17”, “79x17”];
```

The 1st part var a works and is what it should look like.  The second var b is incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: A different font won't help one bit. Copy the text into a text editor, replace the funny quotes with plain `"` characters, and *then* copy/paste it.

Comment: A font doesn't *change* the text, it only affects how it's displayed. You'll have to actually replace the incorrect characters. Any decent text editor will let you do that easily.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  That saved me a lot of work.  I am still new to coding.  I appreciate all your help.